# angular2 show hide contents of header based on user roles

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

New to angular2, My app.component.html looks something like this-

```
<nav *ngIf="rolesArr.length>0" >
<ul>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="home" class="sectionLink">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="manage" class="sectionLink">manage</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="setting" class="sectionLink">setting</a>
  </li>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

 <footer> ... </footer>
```

and here is app.component.ts-

```
export class AppComponent {

  rolesArr: string[];

  constructor(private ps: PostsService, private roleS: Roles) {
    this.rolesArr = roleS.getUserRoles();
  }

}
```

So I am using angular routing to navigate between links. including login. so this nav header and footer loads initially with login window. and as user is not logged in value of string array **rolesArr** is empty. that means no tabs. which is ok.

but when user successfully logged in and move to another component, content of  changes. and string array **rolesArr** gets something too.

but i need to change the view of tabs on header based on logged in user roles. like if array contains admin role all will show. on user role only first tab will show.

Comment: tell which kind of data comes in `rolesArr`?

Comment: Show your login component/function.

Comment: @micronyks rolesArr is a string array, (or simple one string). the logic is something like if it contains string 'admin' then show all three tabs, if contains string 'manager' show only two. if its user show only first one.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by `@Output` and shared service.

Create a service to emit header change event :

```
import { Injectable , Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EventEmitterService {
  @Output() refreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public emitTopHeaderMenuUpdatedEvent(parameters) {
    this.refreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter.emit(parameters);
  }

  public getRefreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter() {
     return this.refreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter;
  }
}
```

In app component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { EventEmitterService } from './event-emitter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public _eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService) { }

ngOnInit() {  
this._eventEmitterService.getRefreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter().subscribe(callBack => {
        console.log('refresh header');
    });
  }
}
```

Change header from inner component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitterService } from './event-emitter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public _eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {    }

  changeHeader(){
     this._eventEmitterService.emitTopHeaderMenuUpdatedEvent(false);
  }
}
```

Explanation :

1. You need to create a service `EventEmitterService` which contains an object of `EventEmitter` `refreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter` which is accessible from child components.
2. In `AppComponent`, `getRefreshTopHeaderMenuEventEmitter()` will return the `EventEmitter` object.
3. Whenever we need to refresh the header, we can set this event object from child by `emitTopHeaderMenuUpdatedEvent()` of shared service as shown above and header will be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at template binding.  Please consider [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) and [ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) to handle this sort of thing.  For your example of an administrator role, you'll want to look at your roles array to determine if the admin role is present, maybe using

`rolesArr.indexOf('admin') !== -1`

Using that 'truthy' statement, you're going to one of many attribute directives like those linked above or 
`[hidden]`
in order to determine what displays and doesn't display on your template based on admin being one of the current roles for the user.

Comment: i do not have problem with the if condition. problem is I am not able to refresh header content(show/hide) when user moves from one route to another. because its out of <router-outlet></router-outlet>.

Comment: I see. It sounds like you need your main application component to know about your user roles.